# Is there a better way to assign constructor parameter in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a class with a various set of optional parameters when instantiated.
I would like to be sure that the user input ONLY the available parameters option, and also add a default value if nothing is passed.

I come with this

```
export enum HexagoneType {
  POINTY,
  FLAT
}

export interface HexagoneOptions {
  center?: Vector2;
  size?: number;
  color?: string;
  type?: HexagoneType;
}

export default class Hexagone {
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  center: Vector2;
  size: number;
  color: string;
  type: HexagoneType;

  constructor(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, options?: HexagoneOptions) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.center = (options && options.center) ? options.center : new Vector2();
    this.size = (options && options.size) ? options.size : 100;
    this.color = (options && options.color) ? options.color : "red";
    this.type = (options && options.type) ? options.type : HexagoneType.POINTY;
  }
}
```

But is there something shorter ?

Comment: We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical example of service locator anti pattern that should be refactored to builder pattern.

```
export class Hexagone {
  constructor(
    private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D,
    private center: Vector2,
    private size: number,
    private color: string,
    private type: HexagoneType
  ) {}
}

export class HexagoneBuilder {
  public center?: Vector2;
  public size?: number;
  public color?: string;
  public type?: HexagoneType;

  constructor(private ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {}

  create() {
    return new Hexagone(
      this.ctx,
      this.center ?: new Vector2(),
      this.size ?: 100,
      this.color ?: "red",
      this.type ?: HexagonType.POINTY
    )
  }
}
```

Sorry if i made some syntax errors, I dont work with ts on daily basis, but you should get the idea...

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

````
export enum HexagoneType {
  POINTY,
  FLAT
}


type Vector2 = readonly [number, number]

export interface HexagoneOptions {
  center: Vector2;
  size: number;
  color: string;
  type: HexagoneType;
}

export default class Hexagone {
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  center: Vector2;
  size: number;
  color: string;
  type: HexagoneType;

  constructor(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D, {
    center = [0,0],
    size=100,
    color="red",
    type=HexagoneType.POINTY
  }: HexagoneOptions) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.center = center;
    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
    this.type = type;
  }
}
```
````